# To provision AWS S3 Buckets, why Pulumi have Bucket and BucketV2 resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pulumi

I trying to find the story behind having [Bucket](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/aws/api-docs/s3/bucket/)  and [BucketV2](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/aws/api-docs/s3/bucketv2/), and the real difference between the two . Moreover, it looks like for a [lot of S3 resources](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/aws/api-docs/s3/), there is a V2 variant. Why does the V2 variant exists? Why do we have Bucket and BucketV2? Did AWS changed their S3 API, which caused Pulumi to change the provider, and that creates a V2 variant? Is this change rooted in Terraform, and somehow reflected on Pulumi? Bucket and BucketV2 creates the same S3 bucket, but through different APIs, to the Pulumi user? BucketV2 supersedes Bucket? Will Bucket be deprecated?

Comment: This is API versioning.  Adding new features to an API, signaling to the dev that the new version is available with "v2", but not breaking existing users by leaving the old version unchanged.  S3 rarely deprecates old APIs, for instance [ListObjects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjects.html) isn't documented as going away anytime soon, though it is recommended to use ListObjectsV2 for new code.

Comment: @AnonCoward, thanks for comment. I get that it is an API versioning. But its not clear to me the why we have this on Pulumi. Is it reflecting an AWS API versioning? What is the roadmap for that (on pulumi)? what is the advantage of using v2? The question intetnds to get references and explanations about that.